# How to reset the font-size on clicking android phone back button?

Tags: android

I'm having a TextView and i set the font size to 26 to clicking the TextView.
Now i need to reset the font size to 22 while pressing the back button of android phone.

How can i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: "Now i need to reset the font size to 22 while pressing the back button of android phone." -- please don't. Users will not expect the BACK button to behave this way. Please use something else (button, action bar item, menu item) to trigger your font size changes in a fashion that does not break user expectations.

Answer (score 1):

override this method

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
      // set size here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you want to do this, as the activity is destroyed when you click back button, whatever this is what you would want to do...

```
public class YourClass extends Activity{

 public static final int INITIAL_FONT_SIZE = 22;
 public static final int ACTIVITY_FONT_SIZE = 26;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        yourTextView.setTextSize(ACTIVITY_FONT_SIZE);
     }


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
       yourTextView.setTextSize(INITIAL_FONT_SIZE);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

But the question is why do you want to reset back the Text size on backbutton press, as coming back to the activity again will reset it back to 26..

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add OnClickListener for TextView like Below one

```
TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
t.setOnClickListener(this);
```

on in

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    t.setTextSize(22);

}
```

And Reset TextView size to your required when trigger Back Key.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
   yourTextView.setTextSize(22);
}
```